# Tweaking a netbook's default resolution

Tags: resolution, netbook

I have come across many online guides that enable tweaking the netbooks default 1024 × 600 resolution settings, either via registry or display properties to enable higher resolutions. Is that truly (technically) possible? If yes, what are the knacks (side effects) to it, especially on the processor/performance front?

Comment: Example: http://mobileoffice.about.com/od/netbooks/a/How-To-Change-Your-Netbooks-Screen-Resolution.htm

Comment: Side effects vary from display panel to display panel, no way to know other than try it, remember its a reg hack, reg hacks usually have side effects.

Answer (score 0):

Though it is possible to change the resolution of the netbooks to a higher resolution like 1024x768. However, it is not a native resolution and you will have a squished screen so that everything fits or it will be scrollable. It is best and easiest on the eyes to leave the netbook at the recommended native resolution. The only time that I would suggest something like this is if you had to install a program on the netbook that required a minimum screensize that was not native to the netbook.